# Create a bubble plot without line connections

Tags: r, ggplot2

Having a dataframe like this:

```
data.frame(month = c("03-2012","04-2012","05-2012","06-2012","07-2012", "08-2012","09-2012","10-2012","11-2012","12-2012","02-2013","03-2013"), frqp = c("12.3", "11.4","44.1","11.3", "1.2","15.1","35.1","12","14.1","15.1","15.1","42.1")
```

How is it possible to plot in x axis the month column and y axis the frqp column ( it is percentage score) and have in the plot on the dots/bubbles without a line connection?

Comment: Hope the provided solution is what you are intending to plot? Have edited to maintain the order of x-axis as available in the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you are looking for a scatter plot? This can be further improved, if this is what you are intending to plot..

```
ddft=data.frame(month = c("03-2012","04-2012","05-2012","06-2012","07-2012", "08-2012","09-2012","10-2012","11-2012","12-2012","02-2013","03-2013"), frqp = c("12.3", "11.4","44.1","11.3", "1.2","15.1","35.1","12","14.1","15.1","15.1","42.1"))
ddft$month <- factor(ddft$month, levels = ddft$month) #maintain X-axis order
ggplot(ddft, aes(x=month, y=frqp)) + geom_point()
```

[image: Output]

Size the dots according to frequency value:

```
ggplot(ddft, aes(x=month, y=frqp)) + geom_point(aes(size=frqp))+ theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image: Size of dots mapped to frequency]

For keeping only the year values:

1. Function to retain last n characters in a string

   ```
   lastfew <- function(x, n){
     x=as.character(x)
     substr(x, nchar(x)-n+1, nchar(x))
   }
   ```
2. Apply the function on the month column

   ```
    yearlabels=lastfew(ddft$month,4)
   ```
3. Create the plot

   ```
    ggplot(ddft, aes(x=month, y=frqp)) + geom_point(aes(size=frqp))+ theme(legend.position="none") + scale_x_discrete(labels= yearlabels)
   ```

[image]

For details of scale_x_discrete:
[Refer: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_discrete.html](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_discrete.html)

4. Further aggregate to only two values in the x-axis:

   ```
    ggplot(ddft, aes(x=yearlabels, y=frqp)) + geom_point(aes(size=frqp))+ theme(legend.position="none")
   ```

[image: x-axis squeeze]

Comment: thank you. Is it possible to show in the graph in the x -axis only the two years? 2012 and 2013 this two values

Comment: Have added the same, hope you find it useful.